# Django Queryset compare two different models with multiple rows

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I have these two models that I would like to return the sum of. I get an database error about the subquery returning more than one row. What would be the best way to compare both without using a for statement?

```
AuthorizationT(models.Model)
  ar_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  status_flag = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
BillT(models.Model)
  paid_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  recvd = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Query I tried

```
paidbill= BillT.objects.values_list('paid_id', flat=true)
AuthorizationT.objects.values().filter(ar_id=paidbill, status_flag=0).aggregate(Sum('recvd'))
```

In SQL I know it would be

```
select sum(recvd) from authorization_t a, bill_t b where a.ar_billid0= b.paid_id and a.status_flag=0
```

I'm looking for the equivalent in queryset

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't be able to achieve without a `for loop` because I think you need to join the tables as there is a filtration on both tables and you want to sum a field from the first table. The way to join tables would be `prefetch_related()` or `select_related()` but they utilize foreign keys.

This leads me to a suggestion that the `id fields: bill_id and ar_id` should be normalized as it looks like there will be data duplication. Using a relationship would also make making queries simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Since `paidbill` is a list, you have to use the `__in` suffix in your query:

```
AuthorizationT.objects.filter(ar_id__in=paidbill,status_flag=0).aggregate(Sum('recvd'))
```

If you model the relation of the models (`ar_id`, `paid_id`) via a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToMany`, you will be able to do this trivially in a single ORM statement

Comment: I think the issue here would be aggregate wont work because the field is part of model `BillT`. The issue is from the original query